# Кнопка перейти на каталог выше в делфи

Tags: delphi, pascal

Мне нужно реализовать кнопку, при нажатии на которую я бы смог подняться на один каталог выше. Я использую компоненты `TListView` и `TImageList`.

Comment: `cd..`    Как компоненты относятся к каталогам?

Comment: Приложение под какаю операционную систему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  currentFolder := ExtractFileDir(currentFolder);
  ShowCurrentFolderContent;
end;
```